# Proving a friend wrong about continuity

Tags: epsilon-delta

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by the rule that $f(x)=1$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=2$ if $x \geq 0$. A friend asserts that $f$ is continuous at the point $x=0$, and you of course disagree. A symbolic formulation of your friend's assertions is:

$\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists\delta > 0$ $\forall x \left( |x-0| < \delta \Rightarrow | f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon \right)$.

My job is to prove this friend wrong.

I figure the solution is to prove the negation.

i.e. prove:$\exists \epsilon > 0$ $\forall\delta > 0$ $\exists x \left( |x-0| < \delta \Rightarrow | f(x) - f(0)| \geq \epsilon \right)$.

If I am correct in my reasoning then I am not sure how to prove the negation as I have not proved an epsilon delta type proof before and we have not gone over it in lecture nor do we have a text to use.

Comment: What do you think is the negation of the continuity condition?

Comment: Just give your friend $\epsilon = 1/2$ and ask them to give you $\delta$.

Comment: "I figure the solution is to prove the negation. i.e. prove..." Good idea. What is the negation, already (you copied the assertion itself, it seems)?

Comment: The negation is that $\exists\, \epsilon>0$ such that  $\forall \delta>0$ $\exists x$ with $|x-0|<\delta$, such that $|f(x)-f(0)|>\epsilon$.

Comment: you are absolutely right... I had copied the wrong statement

Comment: I fail to see how $\epsilon = 1/2$ is a counter example.

Comment: Burgundy, if I give you $\epsilon = 1/2$, can you give me $\delta$?

Comment: I see it now thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\epsilon_0 < 1$. Then $|f(x) - f(0)| = |2 - f(x)| = |2 - 1| = 1$ for any $x < 0$. And clearly $1 > \epsilon_0$.